# Grails: Adding user roles in Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I'm using the Spring Security version 2-RC4 plugin in Grails in my web application, and am a little unsure how to add roles to an individual user

I used the quickstart script and this successfully created `User`, `Role` and `UserRole` domain classes, but only controllers for `User` and `Role`.

Section 3.3 refers to helper methods for adding roles to users, but I was hoping to just use a scaffolded gsp to map a `User` to a `Role`.
I performed a `create-scaffold-controller` against the `UserRole` domain class, but when I attempt to create new mapping I get this exception:

```
No such property: generator for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.CompositeIdentity
```

Therefore, I'm wondering if there is any way to map these out of the box? I would have presumed that having a generated gsp would be the obvious way to achieve this

Comment: Have you looked at the Spring Security UI plugin on github for how it's done there? That might be a place to pick up a few tips and tricks. https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/

Comment: I don't see any reference documentation associated with this plugin

Comment: From the plugin portal you can click on documentation. It takes you here: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the Wiki section